# Is the switch-function SQL-injection safe?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I'm trying to access entries from the database with variable column names.

I have this table containing vehicles that can belong to one of three categories (car, bike, truck):

| vehicle | car | bike | truck |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car 1 | x |  |  |
| Car 2 | x |  |  |
| Bike 1 |  | x |  |
| Truck 1 |  |  | x |

With OOP and PDO, I'm trying to access the vehicles that belong to a category. Like so:

User-input:

```
 URL: ?category=cars
```

All of the following is inside a class called "Vehicles".

Constructor of class Vehicles:

```
public function __construct() {

  $this->category = $_GET["category"] ?? "cars";

  switch ($this->category) {
  default: //Avoiding db-error messages by setting default category to "car"
  case "cars":
    $this->category = "car";
    break;
  case "bikes":
    $this->category = "bike";
    break;
  case "trucks":
    $this->category = "truck";
    break;
 }
```

I then access the entries from the db that correspond to the category:

```
public function getVehiclesFromCategory() {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE $this->category IS NOT NULL";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql);

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $row["vehicle"]."<br>";
    }
}
```

I then create the object to get the output from the chosen category:

```
$Vehicles = new Vehicle();
$Vehicles->getVehiclesFromCategory();
```

I'm basically relating the user input to a predefined value. Is this sufficient to avoid SQL-injections?

I do realize I'm using a bad db-design, as the user is not supposed to get any hints about the names of the db-columns. I am also aware that I should avoid db-related error messages that can be useful for hackers (which is why I use the default-switch) - but I need a quick fix for now with the current db-model.

Comment: How would you use prepared statements to get column names? I had problems with that which is why I resorted to switch.

Comment: It looks generally OK. But the DB design isn't bad because of "hints about the names of the db-columns". But, unless a vehicle can be of several types, a column that denotes the type might be the better choice. If a vehicle can have several types, a bridging table between vehicles and type might be better.

Comment: @stickybit Is it empty if I didn't use break? Doesn't it just become the same as case "cars"? A column denoting the type is problematic, because the table shown here is very simplified. There are 50 categories and each vehicle can belong to several of them.

Comment: The thing about the default was my fault. I already edited that wrong part out.

Comment: So you have 50 columns? o_O That's why that is a bad design. Whenever you need a new category you need a new column. Relational tables aren't spreadsheets. If you need to change columns when adding new data, that's a strong indicator the schema is fundamentally flawed... Have a separate table for the types and a bridge table assigning vehicles to types.

Comment: @stickybit yes exactly. I'm working on a new and better db that takes care of the categories. But for now I really need this to work and be safe enough until then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though this question (*"is it safe?"*) has been answered already. However, the how and why seem to be a bit up in the air so here's some further information...

### Why it's *safe*

The **ONE** thing that is saving you from SQL injection in this case is the fact that you set a `default` case in your `switch` statement. Without that one word you would be wide open to SQL injections. Let's play it out:

**Valid input example**

1. User input `bikes`
2. Your code sets the `category` property to `bikes`
3. Your `switch` runs and `bikes` is found so it returns `bike` as the `category`

**Invalid input example**

1. User input `hairStraightener`
2. Your code sets the `category` property to `hairStraightener`
3. Your `switch` runs and `hairStraightener` isn't found so it returns `car` as the `category`; which is the `default` case

**Invalid case without default**

1. User input `hairStraightener`
2. Your code sets the `category` property to `hairStraightener`
3. Your `switch` runs and `hairStraightener` isn't found so `category` isn't updated and remains as `hairStraightener`

Now, imagine a user had put something like:

```
1; DROP TABLE vehicles; --

// OR...

1; UPDATE TABLE vehicles SET price = 1; --
```

Now you've lost a load of data or everything in your shop costs £1 (bargain!)

### Improving things

You're on the right lines: if you need to input a variable directly into the SQL query you need to whitelist acceptable items and only use those. There are different ways of doing it...

1. As you have with a `switch/case`
2. With a `match` (PHP 8+)
3. With an `array` and lookup
4. By checking variables against the DB schema

**Switch**

The biggest problem I see with the way you've done is that if someone comes along and looks at your code they may well see that you've effectively *set a default* before the `switch` and therefore remove the `default` case; which would leave you open to SQL injection.

So you should update your code accordingly:

- Don't ever set the user input to the `category` property
- Set the default property of `category` on declaration

E.g.

```
public $category = "car";

public function __construct()
{
  switch ($_GET["category"] ?? null) {
    case "cars":
        $this->category = "car";
        break;
    case "bikes":
        $this->category = "bike";
        break;
    case "trucks":
        $this->category = "truck";
        break;
    }
}
```

**Match**

As commented by [@Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) if your server is running PHP 8+ you can use `match`. Which, in this case, you can think of as a type sensitive `switch` statement:

*Note: `match` will throw an error if you don't supply the `default` case; or rather if a value is supplied that can't be matched!*

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->category = match($_GET["category"] ?? "cars") {
        "cars"   => "car",
        "bikes"  => "bike",
        "trucks" => "truck",
        default  => "car"
    };
}
```

**Array lookup**

```
private $allowedFields = [
    "cars"  => "car",
    "bikes" => "bike",
];

public function __construct()
{
  $this->category = $this->allowedFields[$_GET["category"] ?? "cars"];
}
```

**DB Schema**

Finally, you could auto-generate the *safe* fields by checking the DB schema (something like `DESCRIBE vehicles`) and checking the input matches one of the column names. In your case though this probably isn't the best idea because you could still have someone input a *real field* which wasn't intended. Maybe it wouldn't be catastrophic, but it definitely isn't intended!

### Fixing things long term

As others have said this is a largely flawed DB design. Presumably looking something like:

```
vehicles
    id
    make
    model
    price
    ...
    bike
    car
    van
    truck
    ...
```

When it should look more like:

```
vehicle     <    vehicleType      >    type
    id              id                    id
    make            vehicle_id            name
    model           type_id
    price
    ...
```

You then update your SQL to look something like:

```
SELECT
    vehicle.id, vehicle.make, vehicle.model, vehicle.price,
    type.name
FROM vehicle
JOIN vehicleType on vehicle.id          = vehicleType.vehicle_id
JOIN type        on vehcileType.type_id = type.id
WHERE type.name = ?
```

Now you can used a prepared statement to be fully safe

**N.B.**

It may seem like creating two tables and updating the existing one into them is a time consuming process. But in reality it won't take that long. The process:

1. Create the tables with appropriate datatypes, properties, etc.
2. `DESCRIBE` the `vehicles` table and extract the different types (`car`, `bike`, etc.)
3. Insert the types into the table `type`

   - This can all be done automatically with a few lines of PHP, for example
4. Write a short script to loop through each line of your vehicles table and `insert` records into the `vechicleType` table based on what columns are `not null`
5. Check your data (backup as required)
6. Remove the no longer needed columns from `vehicles`

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:
Yes

Long answer:

Yes you are,
because you dont actualy use the user input as an database field they cant manipulate it.

Aslong you doesnt directly put user input into your database you wont get problems with mysql injections.

Many People tell you to use prepared statments at every request, but you only have to use them if you directly use userinput in your querys like a username order an email.

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that in this case, parameters and prepared statements can't be used in any case because the OP is injecting a column name, not a value.

Answer (score -1):

you are running a bad design when you take the coulmn as a parameter.

however, the code as is, would be safe because it's fixed.

please do at least.
replace :
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE $this->category IS NOT NULL";

$param = $usetheconnection->real_escape_string($this->category);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE `{$param}` IS NOT NULL";

then redo the design